# Litespeed Rewrite Rules

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting, litespeed

Trying to figure out how to get the following rewrite rule changed to work with Litespeed.

Previously the below rewrite rule worked with Apache, but stopped working with Litespeed.

```
 RewriteRule ^product-page/category-one/ index-redir.php 
 [L,E=URI:/category-one/]
 RewriteRule ^category-one/ /product-page/category-one/ 
 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: I'm assuming those directives are written on one line, not "split" like you have here? What URL(s) are you requesting? What are you expecting to happen? In what way did it "stop working" exactly? What other directives do you have?

Comment: Hi MrWhite. Thank you for your response. The first two lines are on one line, and the third and forth lines are on one line. Litespeed causes an infinitive loop, whilst with Apache the above works smoothly.

Comment: What type of "infinitive loop" specifically? The above alone should not result in an "infinite loop" on LiteSpeed, hence the other questions in my comment.

Comment: The page seems to redirect back to itself. Have tested on our local development site on Apache, and everything works as it should. Still baffled as to why Litespeed doesn't like the above rewrite.

Comment: So, it's a "redirect loop"? (As opposed to a "rewrite" loop.) You need to check the details in the network tab of the browser dev tools. As mentioned, there is no (redirect) loop in the directives you've posted (not on LiteSpeed, or Apache). However, you are setting an env var in the first rewrite - what is this for? This can behave differently on Apache vs LS - depending on what other directives you have. What does `index-redir.php` do? Is `redir` short for "redirect"??

Comment: In the network tab it's showing a 301 moved permanently pointing to the website home page, which is were this is redirecting back to. It then shows a 200 status on the home page url, showing that the status has succeeded. index-redir.php file contains the following, which I think now could be the cause, and prehaps this behaves differently on Litespeed than Apache. $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"] = $_SERVER["REDIRECT_URI"]; include("index.php");

Comment: "showing a 301 moved permanently pointing to the website home page" - Right, so that doesn't appear to relate to the directives in your question. And what's in `index.php`? Something is triggering a redirect.